# How to compare 1 row in 1 table with multiple rows in multiple tables for inequality/equality in Oracle using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle

I want to compare 1 table's data(rows) Say Table 1, with Table 2 & Table 3 Data(rows).
I don't know how to proceed with it ? 
Please help me related to this question.
I want to write PL/SQL script to check the same with column's data type.

Comment: Do you mean you want to identify differences or duplicates?  Are the tables in the same format?

Comment: Show please your table's DDL and explain, what possible results do you expect?

Comment: @pm_2 Thanks for Your Response! I want to compare 2 tables for differences. These tables are in the same schema.One more thing about tables is they does not contain equal no. of columns. Please guide me how to compare such tables & if possible how to compare tables for equal number of columns.

Comment: @Dmitry These tables are in the same schema.Tables doesn't contain equal no. of columns. But data types of columns which are same in both the tables are same.Please guide me how to compare such tables & if possible how to compare tables for equal number of columns with same data type.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I fully understand your question.  However, this might get you started.

Given the following structure:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer C
inner join SalesLedger S ON
    S.CustId = C.CustId
inner join Product P ON
    P.ProdId = S.ProdId
```

To return, for example, customers that had not bought a specific product, you might use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer C
where c.custid not in
(
    select s.custid 
    from SalesLedger S 
    inner join Product P ON
        P.ProdId = S.ProdId
    where p.prodid <> 1
)
```

If you provide some more detail about you specific problem then I might be able to provide a more specific answer.